# timeout-error when testing login-dialog using protractor and angular-strap modal

Tags: javascript, angularjs, testing, protractor, angular-strap

I have a login-dialog using a angular-strap modal, which gets invoked by:

```
scope.authModal = $modal({
                template: '/components/login/login.html',
                show: false,
                scope: scope,
                backdrop: 'static'
            });
```

(that code is inside the link function of a login-directive.)

Now, my protractor code looks like this:

```
it('should perform login properly', function () {
    browser.manage().deleteAllCookies();
    element(by.model('login.username')).sendKeys('xy123');
    element(by.model('login.password')).sendKeys('abz89');
    element(by.binding("guiText.loginButton")).click();
    browser.waitForAngular();
    expect(element(by.id('login.username')).isPresent()).to.eventually.equal(false);
});
```

In another test above the `element(by.id('login.username')).isPresent()` has been proved to equal true when the login-dialog is visible.

The problem is, I'm getting `Error: timeout of 10000ms exceeded` with that test. In the browser I can see, that the credentials are typed in correctly and the button is being clicked. The login modal disappeas and then nothing happens and the browser is eventually running in to that timeout exception after waiting 10 seconds.

Comment: When you test manually it works OK?

Comment: Yes, it works when trying out manually.

Comment: Can you provide a plnkr?

Comment: how do i do that with protractor?

Comment: Are you using `.to.eventually.equal(false)` to poll the value of `isPresent()`?

Comment: Hi, I have the same problem, were you able to find a solution?

Comment: Have you taken a look at http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/timeouts and made sure that nothing on your page is polling using the `$timeout` service?

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem and I did below to solve this.

Write this function in your helper file and call this to click on login button in your code. Try to access the button by Id and then pass the id in this function, if not id then update the function as per your need

```
var clickAndWait= function (btnId) {
    var returnVal = false;
    browser.wait(function () {
        if (!returnVal) {
            element(by.id(btnId)).click().then(function () {
                returnVal = true;
            });
        }
        return returnVal;
    }, 30000);
};
```